# Global variable doesn't transfer its value to a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I develop a MS Access tool in a multiuser environment. Based on the login different users have different views and get different information.

So my problem is that the global variable which I have declared in a module does not save and transfer the information to the form, which I want to be fitered based on the criteria.

Here is the code for the global variable (module level) setting which works perfectly.

```
Option Compare Database

Global GBL_Username as String

Public Function Init_Globals() As String
    GBL_Username = Forms!frm_Login.txtUsername

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Login"

    frm_Login.Visible = False

    Forms!frm_Login.txtUsername.Value.Enabled = False
End Function
```

In the form which should be filltered I call the function and set it in the filter field (`txtfilterfield`).

However, after many tries I still get some errors, such as "the variable is not defined" or it just shows that the variable is `" "`.

I will be grateful for some help here.

Comment: Globals suck. Why not using the control on the hidden form directly ?

Comment: That is a good idea ... I will try it ...

Comment: nope ... didn't work ... I willl try with something else ...

Answer (score 1):

Try `Public GBL_Username As String`

Comment: Good answer.  Also, Ira, it is critically important to include `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.  This prevents all kinds of name and scope problems with variables by forcing you to declare them using `Dim`, `Public`, etc.

Comment: Hi! that is not the problem .. even if I declare it with Global or Public and put the Option Explicit above the codes .. The Variable stays (so the code actually reads it), but doesn't use it later by the code for the form. :(

Comment: If you encounter an unhandled error in your code, all the variables, including your public/global variables go back to default value. Maybe that's the case? If you have put your variable in a module with the syntax in my answer, it should work just fine.

Comment: That's why I recommend to use a hidden control instead of a global variable. 1) It is not reset by stopping code AND 2) you can make it visible during development AND 3) it is accessible by queries.

Comment: Your first remark is absolutely true. making your vars visible however, can be done by adding a few simple watches in your vba editor and you can also assign your publics to queries by creating a simple function which assigns the variable to the function. That aside, I also prefer the use of hidden controls!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be an answer but its too long for a comment hence posting as answer.

Your function does not return any value and therefore does not make any sense in terms of what you want to achieve.

lets try line by line:

```
Public Function Init_Globals() As String
    'Receive the username from a textbox called txtusername? if yes you should use txtUsername.value. if txtusername is a db field your should use frmlogin.[txtusername] << strongly not recommended
    GBL_Username = Forms!frm_Login.txtUsername

    'Open the login form thereafter? how can you receive the username in previous code without having the form opened?
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Login"

    'since you have saved/taken your username and saved on a public variable why keeping the login form open and visible? 
    frm_Login.Visible = False

    'I have no clue what this code supposed to do, disable the textbox? if yes you should use txtUsername.enabled = false
    Forms!frm_Login.txtUsername.Value.Enabled = False
End Function
```

Maybe you wanted to do this:

1. Check if user is logged in
2. if not force user to login
3. get the logged in username

in code it would be

```
Public UserName as String

Public Function GET_USER_NAME() as String
   CHECK_LOGIN ' checks if username is already there
   get_user_name = userName ' return the username
End Function

Public Function CHECK_LOGIN()
   if nz(username,"") = "" then ' check if username is empty
      LOGIN ' if empty force relogin
   End Id
End function

Public Function LOG_OUT()
   userName = ""
end Function

Public Function LOGIN()
   docmd.OpenForm "frm_Test", WindowMode:=acDialog
   ' in your login form after successful login save the username into the userName variable
   'something like this. userNAme = me.txt_username.value
End Function
```

to get the logged in username you would call the function "get_user_name" like

```
 dim crr_user  as string
 crr_user = get_user_name
```

**note**: i haven't checked for errors, i just wrote from my head.

Here some logic idea how to work with user logins in Access:

1. Simply use public variable to hold username. when a user logs in after successful login save the username/id in a public variable. use the variable for future use
2. Create a login/logout function which shows login form, after successful login save user details in a "local table" you can then get username by Dlookuping(username, tablename...)
3. Complicated way: create class module "Membership" create getter and setter functions for saving/retrieving user details/login details etc.

maybe check this post someone uploaded sample db:
[Microsoft Access - Show name of logged in user from UserID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500739/microsoft-access-show-name-of-logged-in-user-from-userid)