# Microsoft Access - Show name of logged in user from UserID

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access database I'm working on which has a simple login system consisting of a drop down (combo) menu to select the username, a password field and a users table.

Inside the users table, I'm storing the username, password and the first name of all the users. I've managed to get my login form working, but I'd like the user's first name to be displayed in a text box on the next form.

I've managed to get the user's ID number, and display it in a text box, but I haven't been able to get the user's first name.

Does anyone know of a simple way to display the user's first name in a text box, keeping in mind I'll have several forms where I wish to display the user's first name?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your code for it?

Comment: Declare one global variable and on log-in button click assign value on it using select query and passing userId in it to select first  name. at all the pages put label and on load assign global variable value on it.

Comment: Create one module and then declare like this - Global fname

Answer (score 2):

As your description says you are using a ComboBox, I am sure the RowSource would be.

```
SELECT ID, userNameField
FROM EmpAuth;
```

The ComboBox properties are Bound Column - 1, Column Count - 2, Column Widths - 0cm;2.5cm (something like this, but 0cm for sure). Now all you have to do is, make the following changes, RowSource :

```
SELECT ID, userNameField, firstNameField
FROM EmpAuth;
```

ComboBox properties are Bound Column - 1, Column Count - 3, Column Widths - 0cm;2.5cm**;0cm**

Then, you can simply use the OpenArgs method where you can pass the ComboBoxes Column 3. like,

```
If Me.password.Value = DLookup("password", "EmpAuth", _
        "[ID]=" & Me.username.Value) Then

    ID = Me.username.Value

    DoCmd.OpenForm "POSMenu", OpenArgs:=Me.username.Column(2) 
    'Close logon form and open splash screen
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "AuthenticationService", acSaveNo


Else
  MsgBox.............
```

Then Finally in the Second Form's On Load event you can use.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Len(Me.OpenArgs & vbNullString) > 0 Then _
        Me.yourTextBoxName = Me.OpenArgs
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the user name information in several forms, perhaps you may consider using session variables to access the information. Its a bit more cleaner than passing it from object to object as an argument.

```
'On the login page,upon confirming the login is correct,
'Initialise session variables
TempVars.RemoveAll 'Destroy any previous Session

'Retrieve the username from the table
UserName = Dlookup("Usernamecol","UsersTable","UserID=" & SelectedUSerID
'Load the retrieved username into a global session variable
TempVars.Add "GlbUserName", UserName
'Use this whenever you want to show the user name
LoggedInUser = TempVars![GlbUserName]
Me.txtUserName = LoggedInUser
'or
Me.lblUserName.caption = LoggedInUser
```